# Finding a faster ActiveRecord query (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I have a model that is sorted in a particular order.  My goal is to find a record from the model where the sum of a particular column of all previous records equals a certain number.
The following example gets me what I need, but it is very slow, especially with a rather large table.  Are there any faster ways to solve for the product.id where the sum of all previous products' points = 100000?

```
 total_points = 0
 find_point_level = 100000
 @products = Product.order("id").all
 @products.each do |product|
    total_points = product.points + total_points
    @find_product = product.id
    break if total_points >= find_point_level
 end
```

**Update**

Here are some times for a few of the solutions below. This is going through about 60,000 records. Times are for ActiveRecord.

Original example (above):
2685.0ms
1238.8ms
1428.0ms

Original example using find_each:
799.6ms
799.4ms
797.8ms

Creating a new column with the sums:
181.3ms
170.7ms
172.2ms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try denormalizing your database, and keeping partial sums directly in `products` table. Simple query with `where` and `limit` would return you a proper answer in no time.

You need to create additional filter, that will update single record whenever product is added, and all products whenever product is deleted or it's `points` field were changed.

Comment: after all, your approach is most pragmatic and straightforward. +1

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, there actually is a way to do this in SQL. First, let's set up some testing environment:

```
rails new foobar
cd foobar
rails g model Product name:string points:integer
rake db:migrate
rails console
```

In the Rails console, feed the DB with some records:

```
Product.new(name: 'Foo',  points: 1).save!
Product.new(name: 'Bar',  points: 2).save!
Product.new(name: 'Baz',  points: 3).save!
Product.new(name: 'Baf',  points: 4).save!
Product.new(name: 'Quux', points: 5).save!
```

Now i found a way of getting running totals in SQL [in this post here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3112381/SQL-Server-Calculating-Running-Totals-Subtotals-and-Grand-Total-Without-a-Cursor.htm). It works like this:

```
query = <<-SQL
  SELECT *, (
    SELECT SUM(points)
    FROM products
    WHERE id <= p.id
  ) AS total_points
  FROM products p
SQL
```

Running this query against the test DB gives us:

```
Product.find_by_sql(query).each do |p|
  puts p.name.ljust(5) + p.points.to_s.rjust(2) + p.total_points.to_s.rjust(3)
end

# Foo   1  1
# Bar   2  3
# Baz   3  6
# Baf   4 10
# Quux  5 15
```

So we can now use a `HAVING` clause (and a `GROUP BY` because this is needed for `HAVING`)to fetch only the products that match the condition and `LIMIT` the number of results to one:

```
query = <<-SQL
  SELECT *, (
    SELECT SUM(points)
    FROM products
    WHERE id <= p.id
  ) AS total_points
  FROM products p
  GROUP BY p.id
  HAVING total_points >= #{find_point_level}
  LIMIT 1
SQL
```

I'm really curious how this performs in your environment with many many records. Give it a try and tell me if it works for you, if you like.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. As my data is static, probably the easiest thing is to just add a new field as @samuil suggested.  Thank you for showing me how to do it with an SQL query though.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach, as database content technically is _not_ static. In addition, you cannot order your products by a different column than id with @samuil's approach. Also, you have to keep track of an additional column manually, which generally is a bad thing, because humans make mistakes and may screw things up.

Comment: I'm trying out all of the solutions now and I'll report back on the times. @padde you mention some important trade-offs.

Comment: now that i think about it, does this even work ? this query won't get @diasks2 to find the record id unless we use `SELECT id, SUM(points) OVER(ORDER BY id)` - and i'm not sure he uses a db that supports window functions.

Comment: I haven't gotten either this one or @m_x's to work yet.  I'm not too familiar with writing raw SQL in rails. Can I just use the exact code from above? I get a `NoMethodError (undefined method 'query'` error.

Comment: @diasks2 there's a missing `=` between `query` and `<<-SQL`, but as i said in a previous comment, i'm not even sure this query does what you want, that's why i deleted my own answer

Comment: @diasks2, which db do you use ? it is possible to write a sql query if your db supports window functions.

Comment: I use SQLite and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the new answer. Still having some trouble getting it working though.  Probably due to my lack of knowledge on how to execute raw SQL properly in Rails. I'll let you know if I get it working.

Comment: Be aware that this query still has a large complexity. Basically, you're retrieving i rows for every i-th row in the subquery. This results in a complexity of approx. `O(n^2)`, which is considerably bad. With 25.000 rows, this takes quite a while in my test and results in Rails automatically aborting the query. By default, this happens if the query takes longer than 0.5s and all you get is a call to `DESCRIBE` in the log, instead of the actual results. Besides, this approach is not very portable, because the query may not work in every db. Long story short: just stick with @samuil's answer.

Answer (score 0):

- this does not really solve the problem, but you can use `find_each` instead of `each` to load products in batches instead of loading all the table. see the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches)

**EDIT** ignore the following, i forgot that window functions do not permit WHERE and HAVING clauses

- <strike>if you are willing to use a non db-agnostic solution, you can use this (not tested):</strike>

  ```
  query = <<-SQL
    SELECT id, SUM(points) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS total_points
    FROM products
    HAVING total_points >= 100000
    LIMIT 1
  SQL

  @product = Product.find_all_by_sql( query )
  ```

this uses window functions that are NOT supported by all RDBMS (Postgresql does). Beware, once you have retrieved the `@product`, it will be a readonly record with only two attributes accessible: `id` and `total_points`

Comment: more on window functions : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score -2):

If table is very big, you can use plain sql query:

```
find_point_level = 100000
Product.find_all_by_sql("SELECT SUM(points) FROM (SELECT points FROM products ORDER BY id LIMIT #{find_point_level}) AS subquery")
```

Also for column index should be exist index in the database.

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot about working 'limit' and 'sum' together.